# MS Access: Why does the asynch method cause "Run-time error 424: Object required" on an XML/DOM file?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, dom

I am trying to write a simple MS Access application to read a collection of files in XML format.  I've written a few lines of code that should take a document name supplied via a form, open the document, a display some detail of the contents.  However, the code always fails at a preliminary step with the asynch method.  Taking this out would cause the rest of the code to execute before the document is loaded so it is a mandatory step.

I've checked the libraries referenced and tried to instantiate the document as "microsoft.XMLDOM", "MSXML2.DOMDocument" and "MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0" but still get the same error.

The code fails at the line "Set xmlDoc.async = False" with run-time error 424.

The libraries referenced are:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library
- Microsoft XML, v6.0

  ```
  Option Compare Database 
  Option Explicit

  Private Sub ProcessButton_Click()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Dim xmlSourceList As Object
    Dim xmlSource As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Set xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load (Me.ReportFilename)

    Set xmlSourceList = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//DataSources")

    For Each xmlSource In xmlSourceList.childNodes
       MsgBox xmlSource.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name").Text
    Next xmlSource
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set "some object" = true/false is not what you want.

You want:

```
xmlDoc.async = False
```

The use of the word "set" is for setting a object, not changing some properity or method of the xml doc.

Comment: Aha!  I missed that.  Yes, that works now.  Thanks very much.